# How do you draw a line that only splits at 90 degree angles?

Tags: java, android, drawing, paint, touch-event

I am making a logic simulator app in Android Studio and I want to have the wire drawing to be horizontal, and if there is an angle, then a vertical line(no diagonal lines).

Currently my line draws the shortest route from one object on the grid to the next.

```
public void drawWires(Canvas canvas, Paint paint){

    if (inputA != null){ drawWire(canvas, paint, inputA); }
    if (inputB != null){ drawWire(canvas, paint, inputB);}
}
public void drawWire(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, LogicNode input) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    canvas.drawLine( input.getX() +  input.getW() * 3/4,
            input.getY() + input.getH() * 1/ 2,
            this.getX() + this.getW() * 1/4,
            this.getY() + this.getH()* 1/2, paint);

}
```

[how I want the line to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Wdy.jpg)
This is how the drawing looks on the app: http://prntscr.com/q17rpg
...
What I have done so far to implement the new wiring:

1. acquire the X and Y on ACTION_DOWN
2. acquire the X and Y on ACTION_UP
3. Calculate midpoint from both Xs and both Ys
4. Calculate Hypotenuse

At this point I am struggling to figure out what I need to do with the values I have. Is it simpler than this? I was thinking that I need the point where the line splits (X,0) and (0,Y) which I should have from getting the midpoint values.

Answer (score 1):

When you call [`drawLine(float startX, float startY, float stopX, float stopY, Paint paint)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawLine(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)), and you want a *horizontal* line, the values for `startY` and `stopY` must be the same.

When you want a *vertical* line, the values for `startX` and `stopX` must be the same.

Your code has:

```
canvas.drawLine(input.getX() + input.getW() * 3/4,
                input.getY() + input.getH() * 1/2,
                this.getX() + this.getW() * 1/4,
                this.getY() + this.getH() * 1/2, paint);
```

That is not an attempt to draw a *horizontal* line, or a *vertical* line.

To draw 2(!) lines to connect `(startX, startY)` to `(stopX, stopY)`, first line *vertical* and second line *horizontal*:

```
// Draw vertical line (using same X value)
canvas.drawLine(startX, startY,
                startX, stopY, paint);

// Draw horizontal line (using same Y value)
canvas.drawLine(startX, stopY,
                stopX, stopY, paint);
```